# How to printing using for loop on same line in python?

Tags: python

I am trying to make a file like visual for one of my programs. There's `child_data` and `parent_data`

And i'm trying to make the output similar to:

```
parent_data
----------|child_data
           child_data
           child_data
--------------------|grandchild_data
                     grandchild_data
----------|child_data
parent_data
```

My first try I used some like this:

```
def visual(self, ID):
     for i in range(self.generation(ID)): # finding how many parents of the ID 
         print(----|, end='')             # there are
```

But that didn't work, it was printing on the same line but also kept returning NONE when I called to an ID with no parent. So the output would be:
`None parent_data`

Comment: Yes, you can do that.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We expect you to make an attempt at solving problems like this on your own. Please show us what you have tried and what problems you encountered along the way.

Answer (score 1):

The pattern you are going to want to use is to have nodes that keep track of their children, and then use a recursive function to do the printing.

The basic idea of it is this:

```
class Node():
    def __init__(self, name, children=[]):
        self.children = children
        self.name = name

    def print(self, level=0):
        print('\t'*level, self.name)
        level += 1
        for child in self.children:    
            child.print(level)

a = Node('parent', [ Node('child', [ Node('grandchild') ]) ])

a.print()
```

But to get the exact output in you were wanting, you would need to do something like this:

```
class Node():
    def __init__(self, name, children=[]):
        if not isinstance(children, list):
            children = [children]

        self.children = children
        self.name = name

    def print(self, level=0, special_print=False):
        ''' Recursively print out all of the children in a nice visual way.
        level keeps track of the indentation as we go along.
        special_print prefixes the outputted line with a bunch of --- followed by a |
        This special printing happens whenever there is a change in indentation '''

        if level is 0:
            print(self.name)
        elif special_print:
            print('----------'*level + '|' + self.name)
        else:
            print('          '*level + ' ' + self.name)

        level += 1
        special_print = True
        for child in self.children:
            child.print(level, special_print)
            special_print = bool(child.children)

a = Node('parent_data', [
        Node('child_data'),
        Node('child_data'),
        Node('child_data', [
            Node('grandchild'),
            Node('grandchild')
        ]),
        Node('child_data'),
    ])

a.print()
```

Comment: You don't need the print inside the for loop, since you are printing the child when you call `child.print(level)`

Comment: Thanks. I've removed that extra print statement.